# How can I prevent google mail from displaying a white background before it switches to my dark mode preference?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

When I navigate to my google mail URL, for about one second an empty bright white page displays. Then the mail page appears with my preferences.

Is there something I can change that would prevent that white hot flash?

The URL I use is

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

which does not change during this process.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in a different browser? Clearing cache? A brief blank page while the web app is loading is pretty normal many places. Also, there's an edit button so you can add things to your question: this isn't a forum. Finally, you say this is a work account, so did something change recently? Did you ask your orgs IT?

Comment: How do you have dark mode enabled?  Via frontend browser settings?  Or system settings?  Accessibility settings?  From the `chrome://flags` internal page?  By an extension?  By a GreaseMonkey script?

Answer (score 0):

Users Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox userstyle
[Gmail dark loading screen](https://userstyles.world/style/805/gmail-dark-loading-screen) you need install addon [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/#readme)

Mozilla Firefox users without addon Stylus, add CSS code to "**userContent.css**" file in "chrome" folder your browser profile.

[Guide how to Customizing the Firefox UI with CSS](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/wiki/userchrome/)

```
/* Dark background for "mail.google.com" loading screen */

@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com") {
.la-i > div {
    animation: none !important;
}
#loading, #stb {
/*  color: #Background, #1c1b22 - default firefox dark background hex color, change #HEX color to what u want */
    background-color: #1c1b22 !important;
}
.la-k .la-m,
.la-i > .la-m {
    background: #1c1b22 !important;
}
.la-k .la-l, .la-k .la-r {
    border: 3px none #1c1b22 !important;
}
.msg, .msgb {
/*  color: #Text */
    color: #cccccc !important;
}
.submit_as_link {
/*  color: #Link */
    color: #3fafff !important;
}
```

Restart firefox.